# Python regex replacing string that should not match

Tags: python, regex

**Update**: This issue was caused by a bug in the `regex` module which was resolved by the developer in **[commit be893e9](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/commits/be893e9f7e60946eb8cdec66e5e105f369d9437b)**

If you encounter a similiar problem, update your `regex` module. 
You need version `2017.04.23` or above.

**[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563819/python-regex-vs-re-pattern-mismatch)** for further information.

---

Background: I'm using a collection of regular expression (`english.lex`) in a 3rd party Text2Speech engine to normalize the input text before speaking it.

For debugging purposes, I wrote the script below to see what impact my regex collection actually has on the input text.

**My problem is that it's replacing a regex that [simply does not match](https://regex101.com/r/n6OCBc/2)**

---

### I have 3 files:

**regex_preview.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import codecs
import regex as re

input="Text2Speach Regex Test.txt"
dictionary="english.lex"

with codecs.open(dictionary, "r", "utf16") as f:
    reg_exen = f.readlines()
    with codecs.open(input, "r+", "utf16") as g:
        content = g.read().replace(r'\\\\\"','"')

        # apply all regular expressions to content
        for line in reg_exen:
            line=line.strip()

            # skip comments
            if line == "" or line[0] == "#":
                pass
            else:
                # remove " from lines and split them into pattern and substitue
                pattern=re.sub('" "(.*[^\\\\])?"$','', line)[1:].replace('\\"','"')
                substitute=re.sub('\\\\"', '"', re.sub('^".*[^\\\\]" "', '', line)[:-1]).replace('\\"','"')

                print("\n'%s' ==> '%s'" % (pattern, substitute))

                print(content.strip())
                content = re.sub(pattern, substitute, content)
                print(content.strip())
```

**english.lex** - utf16 encoded

```
# punctuation normalization
"(《|》|⟪|⟫|<|>|«|»|”|“|″|‴)+" "\""
"(…|—)" "..."

# stammered words: more general version accepting all words like ab... abcde (stammered words with vocal in stammered part)
"(?i)(?<=\b)(?:(\w{1,3})(?:-|\.{2,10})[\t\f ]?)+(\1\w{2,})" "\1-\2"
# this should not match, but somehow it does o.O
```

**Text2Speach Regex Test.txt** - utf16 encoded

```
“Erm….yes. Thank you for that.”
```

---

Running the script produces this output with the last regex somehow matching the content:

```
'(《|》|⟪|⟫|<|>|«|»|”|“|″|‴)+' ==> '"'
“Erm….yes. Thank you for that.”
"Erm….yes. Thank you for that."

'(…|—)' ==> '...'
"Erm….yes. Thank you for that."
"Erm....yes. Thank you for that."

'(?i)(?<=\b)(?:(\w{1,3})(?:-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+(\1\w{2,})' ==> '\1-\2'
"Erm....yes. Thank you for that."
"-yes. Thank you for that."
```

---

### What I tried so far:

I created this snipped to reproduce the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import codecs

content = u'"Erm....yes. Thank you for that."\n'
pattern = r"(?i)(?<=\b)(?:(\w{1,3})(?:-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+(\1\w{2,})"
substitute = r"\1-\2"
content = re.sub(pattern, substitute, content)

print(content)
```

But this actually behaves like it should. So I'm at a loss at what's happening here.

Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction for further investigation...

Comment: Your regex will match strings like `abc....abc123` or `abc-abc123`, it cannot match `Erm....yes`.

Comment: I know - I wrote it - and that's exactly my problem: why the hell is the script able to match that regex at all. I suspect it's some kind of encoding issue but I have no idea where I went wrong.

Comment: When debugging Python regexes , a good start is to use `r'text'` style literal strings for the regex expressions. It's too easy to get confused with multiple backslashes and which backslash-plus-character combinations are escapes / which aren't. Try that, and if the problem continues it'll be easier for us to understand and make more suggestions.

Comment: Ok, for clarification, you are suggesting to change the contents of `english.lex` or of the "reproduce snipped"? ( I changed the parts in the "reproduce snipped" and its still working - like before. The main script is still acting up though - like before...)

Comment: IIRC, the python unicode string encoding is UTF-8, not UTF-16, if it matters.

Comment: Issue is fixed, I added a note to the question for everyone that encounters a similar problem to update there regex module. See here for for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563819/python-regex-vs-re-pattern-mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original script is using the alternative [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module instead of the standard library `re` module.

```
import regex as re
```

There's clearly some difference between the two in this case. My guess is that it has something to do with nested groups. This expression contains a capturing group within a non-capturing group, which is way too magical for my taste.

```
import re     # standard library
import regex  # completely different implementation

content = '"Erm....yes. Thank you for that."'
pattern = r"(?i)(?<=\b)(?:(\w{1,3})(?:-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+(\1\w{2,})"
substitute = r"\1-\2"

print(re.sub(pattern, substitute, content))
print(regex.sub(pattern, substitute, content))
```

Output:

```
"Erm....yes. Thank you for that."
"-yes. Thank you for that."
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that one. As some other expressions require look behinds with non-fixed length I switched to the `regex` module instead of `re`. And in my test script I imported `re` without even noticing... Well looks like I just have to simplify the regular expressions. Do you happen to know a good source of information regarding what is `magical` and what not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563819/python-regex-vs-re-pattern-mismatch for reference.