# Python regex module vs re module - pattern mismatch

Tags: python, regex

**Update**: This issue was resolved by the developer in **[commit be893e9](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/commits/be893e9f7e60946eb8cdec66e5e105f369d9437b)**

If you encounter the same problem, update your `regex` module. 
You need version `2017.04.23` or above.

---

As pointed out in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561401/2422125)**
I need **[this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/n6OCBc/4)**:

```
(?i)\b((\w{1,3})(-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+(\2\w{2,})
```

working with the `regex` module too...

```
import re     # standard library
import regex  # https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/

content = '"Erm....yes. T..T...Thank you for that."'
pattern = r"(?i)\b((\w{1,3})(-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+(\2\w{2,})"
substitute = r"\2-\4"

print(re.sub(pattern, substitute, content))
print(regex.sub(pattern, substitute, content))
```

**Output:**

```
"Erm....yes. T-Thank you for that."
"-yes. T..T...Thank you for that."
```

---

**Q: How do I have to write this regex to make the `regex` module react to it the same way the `re` module does?**

Using the `re` module is not an option as I require look-behinds with dynamic lengths.

**For clarification:** it would be nice if the regex would work with both modules but in the end I only need it for `regex`

Comment: To clarify: You need this regex to work with __both__ `re` and `regex`, or just with `regex`?

Comment: Also, literally the first sentence on `regex`'s pypi page is *"This regex implementation is backwards-compatible with the standard ‘re’ module"*, so has somebody already reported this bug?

Comment: Why use `(?<=\b)` instead of `\b` which is a zero-length assertion.

Comment: This is something really weird. I tried `print(regex.search(pattern, content))` and it printed `None`. `print(regex.findall(pattern, content))` prints `[('Erm....', '', '....', 'yes')]`. *There is some bug here.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That really is weird; `regex.search(pattern, content)` gives me `<regex.Match object; span=(13, 25), match='T..T...Thank'>`, and `regex.findall(pattern, content)` gives `[('Erm....', '', '....', 'yes'), ('T...', '', '...', 'Thank')]`.

Comment: It seems like regex supports two different behaviours: _Version 0_ is backwards compatible with re, but _version 1_ isn't. See "Old vs new behaviour" section in [the package's documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/).

Comment: @Styrke: I already tried with `(?V0)`, same behavior.

Comment: `[m.groups() for m in re.finditer(pattern, content)]` and `[m.groups() for m in regex.finditer(pattern, content)]` both produce the same output `[('T...', 'T', '...', 'Thank')]`, so the bug must be in the `sub` function.

Comment: FTR my output for version `regex-2017.4.5` is `"-yes. -Thank you for that."` and not `"-yes. T..T...Thank you for that."` so differences between @WiktorStribiżew and @Rawing might be due to change in `g` flag of `sub` between versions...

Comment: @Rawing I updated the question + BitBucket issue can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/238/not-fully-re-backward-compatible

Comment: Issue is fixed, I added a note to the question for everyone that encounters the same bug to update there `regex` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this bug is related to backtracking. It occurs when a capture group is repeated, and the capture group matches but the pattern *after* the group doesn't.

An example:

```
>>> regex.sub(r'(?:(\d{1,3})x)+', r'\1', '123x5')
'5'
```

For reference, the expected output would be:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?:(\d{1,3})x)+', r'\1', '123x5')
'1235'
```

In the first iteration, the capture group `(\d{1,3})` consumes the first 3 digits, and `x` consumes the following "x" character. Then, because of the `+`, the match is attempted a 2nd time. This time, `(\d{1,3})` matches "5", but the `x` fails to match. However, the capture group's value is now (re)set to the empty string instead of the expected `123`.

As a workaround, we can prevent the capture group from matching. In this case, changing it to `(\d{2,3})` is enough to bypass the bug (because it no longer matches "5"):

```
>>> regex.sub(r'(?:(\d{2,3})x)+', r'\1', '123x5')
'1235'
```

As for the pattern in question, we can use a lookahead assertion; we change `(\w{1,3})` to `(?=\w{1,3}(?:-|\.\.))(\w{1,3})`:

```
>>> pattern= r"(?i)\b((?=\w{1,3}(?:-|\.\.))(\w{1,3})(-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+(\2\w{2,})"
>>> regex.sub(pattern, substitute, content)
'"Erm....yes. T-Thank you for that."'
```

Comment: @Aprillion Nice catch, thanks. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: @Rawing you still have a typo, your produced output is `'"Erm....yes. T-Thank you for that."'
`

Comment: @FabianN. I would like to agree, but it actually does produce `T..T-Thank` on my machine.

Comment: I figured it out; it was necessary to prevent the capture group from matching _at all_. I had to move the lookahead assertion in front of the capture group. Answer updated.

Comment: nice solution... this would be consistent with my theory of not reverting empty match groups from unsuccessful longer match during backtracking (for unsuccessful lookahed, the longer match attempt fails before storing empty match into the `\2` group)

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: the [bug](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/238/not-fully-re-backward-compatible) is now resolved in regex [2017.04.23](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2017.04.23)

just tested in Python 3.6.1 and the original pattern works the same in `re` and `regex`

---

Original workaround - you can use a lazy operator `+?` (i.e. a different regex that will behave differently than original pattern in edge cases like `T...Tha....Thank`):

```
pattern = r"(?i)\b((\w{1,3})(-|\.{2,10})[\t ]?)+?(\2\w{2,})"
```

---

The bug in 2017.04.05 was due to backtracking, something like this:

The unsuccessful longer match creates empty `\2` group and conceptually, it should trigger backtracking to shorter match, where the nested group will be not empty, but `regex` seems to "optimize" and does not compute the shorter match from scratch, but uses some cached values, forgetting to undo the update of nested match groups.

Example greedy matching `((\w{1,3})(\.{2,10})){1,3}` will first attempt 3 repetitions, then backtracks to less:

```
import re
import regex

content = '"Erm....yes. T..T...Thank you for that."'
base_pattern_template = r'((\w{1,3})(\.{2,10})){%s}'
test_cases = ['1,3', '3', '2', '1']

for tc in test_cases:
    pattern = base_pattern_template % tc
    expected = re.findall(pattern, content)
    actual = regex.findall(pattern, content)
    # TODO: convert to test case, e.g. in pytest
    # assert str(expected) == str(actual), '{}\nexpected: {}\nactual: {}'.format(tc, expected, actual)
    print('expected:', tc, expected)
    print('actual:  ', tc, actual)
```

output:

```
expected: 1,3 [('Erm....', 'Erm', '....'), ('T...', 'T', '...')]
actual:   1,3 [('Erm....', '', '....'), ('T...', '', '...')]
expected: 3 []
actual:   3 []
expected: 2 [('T...', 'T', '...')]
actual:   2 [('T...', 'T', '...')]
expected: 1 [('Erm....', 'Erm', '....'), ('T..', 'T', '..'), ('T...', 'T', '...')]
actual:   1 [('Erm....', 'Erm', '....'), ('T..', 'T', '..'), ('T...', 'T', '...')]
```

Comment: That's not really a workaround, that's a modification of the pattern. If you try it with input like `a-abc-abcxy`, it will produce different output than the original pattern.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks for pointing that out. I did some testing regarding the original usecase of this pattern  (see here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560759/python-regex-replacing-string-that-should-not-match) and it is indeed possible that undesired output will be produced e.g. T...Tha....Thanks

Comment: right, not a solution, just a workaround to a subset of problems when you don't need to handle `T...Tha....Thank` and/or if `T-Tha...Thank` output is as good enough as `Tha-Thank` would have been (both are meaningless to me, so I would give my workaround a chance and ask the customer if the workaround is good enough for them)

Comment: also for `T..T..Th...Thank` the lazy pattern gives `Th-Thank` in re but `T-Th...Thank` in regex

Comment: Unfortinually the Text2Speach engine this regex is sanitizing input for is a bit picky and makes awkward breaks or even says 'dot' when there are still some left. Hopefully, the developer will find this post useful and fix this  in the near future...